# adding a p tag to the footer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The code should enter "new text" after the Footer text but I'm having issues loading the function.

```js
function insertParagraph(){
    var newElement = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("new text");
    newElement.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("footer");
    element.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <footer>
        <P>Footer</P>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `getElementsByTagName()` returns a **collection** of elements and collections don't have an `.appendChild` method. You have to append on to a **single** element.

Also, you need to call your function so it can run.

```js
function insertParagraph(){
    var newElement = document.createElement("p");
    newElement.textContent = "new text"; // No need for an explicit text node, just set the text directly

    // querySelector() finds the first element that matches the selector argument
    document.querySelector("footer").appendChild(newElement);
}

insertParagraph(); // You must call a function so it can run.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <footer>
        <P>Footer</P>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function insertParagraph(){
    var newElement = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("new text");
    newElement.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementByTagName("footer");
    element.appendChild(newElement);
}
insertParagraph();
```